# How to implement regex in if statement in dictionaries

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I have the following code snippet:
I want to find the row, with the value is digit (they are integers all the time) on the column/key "Something" and delete the matched row. I have tried it with re.compile()

```
for row in list:
    if re.compile("\d") in row["Something"]:
        print(row)
        del (row)
```

How is the right implementation in this case?

Comment: do you need to filter out data containing digits, or data being all digits (like integers) ?

Comment: Only remove the rows, with digits (they are all the time integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't try remove items from lists while iterating, it doesn't work that well: [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating). Anyway, `del row` has no effect since you're just deleting the name, not the item of the list.

I'm assuming that you want to remove rows if `row["Something"]` is an integer value.

I would rebuild the list using a list comprehension filtering out when the data is digits only (regex can be avoided here by using `isdigit()`):

```
[row for row in lst if not row["Something"].isdigit()]
```

That doesn't take care of negative numbers, mind. For that you would need a regex-type check like `re.match("-?\d+",row["Something"])`

Comment: waste of time? talking with _me_ ? :)

Comment: that was a joke!

Comment: I got it, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting your row, you might want to match those which *do not* contain digits:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'^\D+$')

new_rows = (row for row in lst if rx.match(row))
```

This yields a generator which you could either iterate over or convert it to a list entirely.
Additionally, using `list` as a variable name is a **no-no**.